# Nvidia GPU is not running

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, gpu, tensorflow

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and my Nvidia GPU version is "GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]".

I installed CUDA and its version is "CUDA Version 9.0.176".

And by running the command "cat /usr/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2". I get the following results for the CUDNN version :

```
 CUDNN_MAJOR 7
 CUDNN_MINOR 6
 CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 4
```

The problem is that my GPU is not running and my code is running on CPU.

And the version of TensorFlow, Tensor, etc. versions are:

```
 tensorboard==1.12.0    
 tensorflow==1.12.2
 tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0    
 tensorflow-gpu==1.12.2
```

Is there any compatibility issue in the above configuration?

Comment: To make your code run on GPU, uninstall tensorflow (`pip uninstall tensorfow` and install/let tensorflow-gpu only (`pip install tensorflow-gpu`) if you're using Python 3, use `pip3` instead of `pip`. If you want to install a specific version of TensorFlow, use the following `pip install tensorflow-gpu==x.x.x`, replace x.x.x by the version number you want (exp: 1.13.1)

Comment: when I uninstall the tensorflow as you suggested by running "pip3 uninstall tensorflow". I face an error in code "No module named 'tensorflow.python'".
These configuration remains:
**tensorboard==1.12.2 **   
**tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0**    
**tensorflow-gpu ==1.12.2 **

Comment: Hmm, according to what you posted, you have `tensorflow==1.12.2`. How did you install it? And are you using TensorFlow with Python or another programming language?

Comment: I am using tensorflow with Python and i install the `tensorflow==1.12.2` as mention in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible]

Comment: Okay, then run `pip3 freeze` and check which TensorFlow is installed

Comment: `tensorboard==1.12.2'
`tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0`
`tensorflow-gpu==1.12.2`

Comment: Then you have tensorflow-gpu installed, not tensorflow (tensorflow only on tensorflow-cpu tend for tensorflow that runs on CPU only).
How did you check that your code is running on CPU not GPU?

Comment: using `nvidia-smi` command I check the GPU current processing. And it also give me the processes that using the GPU.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same environment as yours, everything works fine. So it must be that CUDA is not properly installed. 
Please check tensorflow documentation about how to install CUDA and tensorflow-gpu: [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), follow the steps specified for your OS version.

Comment: If when you run your code, get messages like this `I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce MX150 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.5315  `, it means that TensorFlow is running on your GPU.

Comment: I change all the configuration provided in the following link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible] and TensorFlow is unable to detect my GPU. For Device detection, I am using `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())` commands.